# XCode: Preprocessor macros from host target not being found in unit tests

Tags: xcode

In my target setup I have preprocessor macros that set some URLs I use in the my app.  I have some integration tests to test server API integrations we've done.  When I run the unit tests, these preprocessor macros are not found and hence the unit tests do not compile.  It is my understanding that preprocessor macros set up in the host target will be available when running the tests

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring in the preprocessor macros defined in the build settings.

The preprocessor macros build setting is used during the compilation of each file only in the target that these build setting was defined. If you have a standard Xcode project with a target that builds an app, a unit test target and a UI test target, each of these will have there own preprocessor macros. However a build setting for any target can inherit the values defined in the project level, this is done by adding the $(inherited) value.

So you can add the preprocessor macros that you need to share between the targets, in the project's build setting, and make sure that in the target's build settings the preprocessor macro have the $(inherited) value(which they have by default). Make sure to add them to all build configurations (e.g. debug and release).

1. Selecting the **Project's**(above the top target in the left column) build settings and adding shared macros:
   [image: Adding shared macros in the project's build setting]
2. They will be automatically be inherited to all targets:
   [image: They will be automatically be inherited to all targets]